# Need to extract all digits before a full stop and the space prior to it. the digit can be positive or negative

Tags: regex

I Need to extract digits before a full stop.

### Sample Text

```
REFERENCE     DATE     DOC.NUM       INV.AMOUNT     DED    INV.AMOUNT.
91300730      20211018 2151229942    1367579.73    0.00    -1367579.73.
.
91300622      20211013 2151226915     167554.96    0.00     167554.96.
.
91300608      20211013 2151226910    1367579.73    0.00    1367579.73.
.
91300621      20211013 2151226909     729375.52    0.00     729375.52.
```

expected output is : `-1367579.73.`, `167554.96.`, `1367579.73.` and `729375.52.`.

Comment: You could use [`(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\.$`](https://regex101.com/r/bsxb8v/1) and use what is inside group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we can identify a full stop as being a period either followed a newline or the end of the input, we can try:

```regex
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\.(?:\n|$))
```

### Demo

This says to match:

```regex
-?              optional negative sign
\d+             a whole number
(?:\.\d+)?      followed by an optional decimal component
(?=\.(?:\n|$))  followed by dot, then a newline or end of the input
```

Comment: Can't you drop the newline? `$` will match end-line and the end-string. `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\.$)`. Btw, the `-?` must have dropped from the expression by accident.

Comment: The pattern may have to change based on the regex tool or language.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
/\s(-*[0-9\.]*)\.\s/
```